# How to import ATG CRS module in eclipse and customize

Tags: atg

I am new to ATG and i installed ATG CRS 11.2 using CIM and it is installed properly and i am able to access the site but i want to import the CRS module in eclipse and customize the existing code for my learning purpose.
I tried the ways given on net, install atg plugin and trying to import but it is not importing.

Please explain the steps to do same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle A-Team have an article [Building Oracle ATG Commerce With Maven](http://www.ateam-oracle.com/building-oracle-atg-commerce-with-maven/). They have created a [sample github project](https://github.com/oracle/atg-build-tools/tree/master/atg-crs-11.2-maven) which uses CRS 11.2 as the basis for the project.  You should be able to import this as a Maven project within Eclipse.

Comment: Can you tell me simple way than the above one?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new Java Project in Eclipse
2. Using windows browser, go to the location where your Java Project is created.
3. Open the Java Project folder, you will find *.classpath* and *.project* files there.
4. Now, go to your **ATG_ROOT** folder, and find the folder **CommerceReferenceStore/Store**
5. Copy-paste your *.project* and *.classpath* files here.
6. Edit the *.project* file and replace the project name by **CommerceReferenceStore.Store**.
7. CRS also has some other (nested) modules. Do the same for the nested modules you want to import in eclipse.
8. Re-open eclipse, Go to File -> Import -> Other -> Existing Projects into your workspace.
9. Browse to your ATG_ROOT directory and select the **Store** folder
10. Check on "Search for Nested Projects"
11. It will populate a list of all the projects, which you can now import.

> For customizing CRS, it is not recommended to modify the existing CRS
>   code. You can create a new module, and layer it on top of CRS to
>   customize it. For more details on creating a new module above CRS, and
>   doing an **assemble-deploy** via CIM, you can follow this article provided
>   below. It has 3 small parts which can get your task done!

**Here is the article**:
http://learnoracleatg.blogspot.in/2016/12/create-and-deploy-new-atg-module-on-local-from-scratch-part-1.html